# SAS cutting off string during data recode

Tags: sas

On a dataset that is created by:

```
data voa;
    input Address $50.;
    input City $1-15 State $16-17 Zip;
    input Latitude Longitude;
    datalines;
1675 C Street, Suite 201
Anchorage      AK  99501    
61.21       -149.89
600 Azalea Road
Mobile         AL  36609
30.65       -88.15
```

I'm attempting to add a new variable which is essential a recoding of Long and Lat, like so:

```
data voa1;
    set voa;
    if Longitude < -110 then Region = "West";
    if Latitude > 40 and Longitude < -90 and Longitude > -110 then Region = "Mid-West";
    if Latitude > 40 and Longitude > -90 then Region = "North-East";
    if Latitude < 40 and Longitude < -110 then Region = "South";
run;
```

Unfortunately, it seems that SAS is cutting the strings short and leaving them at 4 characters (e.g. "Mid-West" just becomes "Mid-"). If I had to guess I would assume that this is because SAS assigns a certain number of bytes for each value in a column based on the first value in that column, and doesn't dynamically modify the number of bytes based on new values. How do I fix this?

Note: I think a potential fix might be putting the longest potential output (in this case "North-East") first, but this seems like an inelegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nice features of SAS is that you are not forced to define your variables before using them. But if you don't define the variable then SAS must make a guess at what you meant by the code that you write. In your case since the first reference to the new variable `Region` is in the assignment statement:

```
Region = "West"
```

SAS makes the logical decision to define it as a character variable of length 4.

To fix that just add a `LENGTH` statement before the first `IF` statement.

```
length region $10;
```